# Incorrect data returned when web-scraping from Internet Explorer using VBA

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am using VBA code (in MS Access, but this problem should occur regardless of the VBA platform) to scrape specific web pages for particular data:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

' Requires references to    "Microsoft Internet Controls"
' Requires references to    "Microsoft HTML Object Library"

Private mFound As Boolean

Private Sub cmdGetFromIE(BaseURL as string)
    Const SND_ALIAS_SYSTEMEXCLAMATION = 8531
    Dim SW As SHDocVw.ShellWindows
    Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim CtrA As Long
    Dim TStart As Single
    Dim Doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim IncElement As MSHTML.IHTMLElement, TitleElement As MSHTML.IHTMLElement, UserElement As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    ' ...

    Set SW = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
    If SW.Count > 0 Then
        For CtrA = 0 To SW.Count - 1
            Set IE = SW.Item(CtrA)
            If Left(IE.LocationURL, Len(BaseURL)) = BaseURL Then
                TStart = Timer
                IE.Refresh
                Do Until (IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE And Not IE.Busy) Or Timer > TStart + 30
                    DoEvents ' Sleep 1 ' Sleep Windows API call procedure  to sleep 1s
                    Debug.Print IE.LocationName, IE.LocationURL, IE.ReadyState, IE.Busy
                Loop
                If IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE And Not IE.Busy Then
                    Set Doc = IE.Document
                    Set IncElement = Doc.getElementsByClassName("history-item__title ng-binding").Item
                    Set TitleElement = Doc.getElementsByClassName("history-item__details ng-binding").Item
                    Set UserElement = Doc.getElementsByClassName("person-summary__full-name_link font-size-xxl ng-binding").Item
                    Debug.Print CtrA & ";" & Val(Right(IncElement.innerText, 12)) & ";" & TitleElement.innerText & ";" & UserElement.innerText
                    ' Do stuff with the data...
                End If
            End If
        Next
        ' Do more stuff with the data...
    Else
        ' ... Do 'No IE open' stuff...
    End If
End Sub
```

My problem is that if I open `Navigation Page A`, and from there navigate to `Data Page B 1`, the correct data is returned from that page, but if I then navigate back to `Navigation Page A` and then navigate to `Data Page B 2`, which is the same form, but contains different data, this code returns some or all of the same data for `Data Page B 2` as was returned from `Data Page B 1`, despite the data pages being refreshed.

I can even navigate to `Navigation Page A` and then open `Data Page B 1` from it in a new tab, and then go back to the `Navigation Page A` tab and then open `Data Page B 2` in yet another new tab, and I still get the problem that I get some or all of `Data Page B 1`'s data from `Data Page B 2`.

`Data Page B` appears to be an Angular-JS - populated stock form, with different data depending upon the URL's data section, however that shouldn't matter, I want the page's data as it stands at the instant I run the procedure, but whether I have my code do an `IE.Refresh` or not, I still have this problem.

If I try `Set Doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument:Set Doc = Doc.createDocumentFromUrl(IE.LocationURL, "")`, I get a "Permission Denied" error at `Doc.getElementsByClassName`.

How can I scrape `Data Page B` for the correct current data for each IE tab?

EDIT:

I don't necessarily even have to use IE to load the pages, I just need to get the *URLs* from IE, and if there is another way accessible via VBA to load and parse the resultant HTML DOM that will work, I'm open to it.

Comment: Not quite sure I fully understand. Could it be a cache issue? Can you try an IE.Refresh2 with the REFRESH_COMPLETELY constant? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb268230(v=vs.85).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752099(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Eliot, I've tried IE.Refresh and IE.Refresh2, neither give the results I need.  I can use IE's DOM explorer to see the HTML, and can extract the relevant data manually, and it does differ between tabs, but as soon as I use `Microsoft Internet Controls`, some or all of page 1's data gets picked up when trying to scrape page 2.  I'd share the links, but they contain confidential data and require login.

Comment: It is almost as if IE is reading only the initial part of the URL before the # that defines the data to be retrieved since the first part will be the same in all instances, e.g. for https://www.example.com/site/#/document/abcde and https://www.example.com/site/#/document/fghij, I see only abcde's data for the most part, as that was opened first.

Comment: If you've tried Refresh2 with the REFRESH_COMPLETELY and that didn't work, I'm all out of ideas. Perhaps these links can help http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?50564-Internet-Explorer-automation-not-working-with-IE11 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646672/ie-does-not-refresh-after-ajax-get-posts

Comment: @Eliot, the vbaexpress link didn't give an answer, and the SO question was of very limited relevancy.  My problem is that it appears that when I trigger my code, IE will have *already* correctly loaded both/all/any pages, yet I cannot use `Microsoft Internet Controls` to *read* the data.  I'm starting to wonder if `Microsoft Internet Controls` itself is buggy...

Comment: @ Monty Wild, is it possible to reveal the link to that webpage to get a more direct answer? Hard to answer hypothetically.